# How to get form values in vee validate in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I'm currently using vee-validate in vue and I'm stuck with getting form values.
I can get form values when user submitted form but I have to get form values before user submits form. My code is like this.

```
<Form as="el-form" :validation-schema="schema" ref="form"
          @submit="onSave"
          :initial-values="formValues">
...
<el-button :disabled="isFormDirty"...></el-button>
</Form>
<script>
import { Form } from 'vee-validate';
...
computed: {
  isFormDirty(): boolean {
    // I want to get form values here
  }
}
</script>
```

My question is how to get form values how to get form values in `isFormDirty`.
Could anyone suggest any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Emit all the form values on change into your form component. However, isn't this better to do in your form component directly? Is there a reason you want this in the parent component?

Comment: This is element-plus form and I have no access to it

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear from the code you posted. If you look at the documentation, you have to pass 'rules' into your component. I would advise you to read the documentation, it's pretty clear. https://element-plus.org/#/en-US/component/form

Comment: Of course, i know doc. Well, This is combine of Element-Plus + Vee-Validate4.0 + Yup.

Comment: Either make a custom form without element-plus and use vee-valdiate or use the built in validation of your element-plus form. Using both is just difficult without any added value.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you get my question. I must use element plus form as app is based on Element plus framework. Have a look at this. https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/examples/ui-libraries

Comment: I think you don't get my answer then. If you must use element plus, don't use vee-validate but the built-in validation.

Comment: Element-plus validation is much worse than vee-validate. That's why vee-validate added how to use vee-validate in Element-plus